# Sum of specific path in a 2D-Arrray

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

[Given way of traversal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJs9D.png)
[Given String-Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shwmn.png)

So given the String Array it should travers as shown via the red path and give back the sum of the numbers which are on the path (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45).
The directional instructions: "L", "R", "D" or "U" (for left, right,
down, up)

`
**Don't really know if it's even possible to implement a while-Loop inside a for-Loop, wasn't really sure how i should solve this one. **

```
int sumPath(String[][] maze) {
    int sum = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maze[0].length; j++) {
            while (!(maze[i][j].equals("E") & (!(maze[i][j].equals("0"))))) {

                if (maze[i][j].equals("R")) {
                    j++; //move to the right (increase col)
                    
                }
                else if (maze[i][j].equals("D")) {
                    i++; //move down (increase row)

                }
                else if (maze[i][j].equals("L")) {
                    j--; //move to the left (decrease col)

                }
                else if (maze[i][j].equals("U")) {
                    i--; //move up (decrease row)

                }
                else if (!(maze[i][j].equals("R") || maze[i][j].equals("D") || maze[i][j].equals("L") || maze[i][j].equals("U") || maze[i][j].equals("E"))) {
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(maze[i][j]);


                }break;

            }

        }



    }return sum;


}
```

`

Comment: What's your question? Did your code run? If it ran, can you, please, include the results? Were the results expected or unexpected? If it didn't run, what error messages were shown? What problem do you have working on this?  Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: This logic won't work try to print the `i` and `j` variables inside the loop and trace how your indexes are affected.

Comment: Instead of appending "[SOLVED]" to the title, you should accept your own answer. You can do that by clicking on the green checkmark below the post score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So i just figured it out **
*Main thing i did is save the current direction the path is going in a string, and switching to a switch *

```
    int sumPath3(String[][] maze) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    String currDir = "";

    while (!(maze[i][j].equals("E") & (!(maze[i][j].equals("0"))))) {
        if ((maze[i][j].equals("R") | maze[i][j].equals("D") | maze[i][j].equals("L") | maze[i][j].equals("U"))) {
            currDir = maze[i][j];
            switch (currDir) {
                case "R" -> j++;
                case "D" -> i++;
                case "L" -> j--;
                case "U" -> i--;
            }
        } else {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(maze[i][j]);
            switch (currDir) {
                case "R" -> j++;
                case "D" -> i++;
                case "L" -> j--;
                case "U" -> i--;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In your while loop, you use an `&` (bitwise and) instead of `&&` (logical and).
2. You can essentially just remove the for loops as you just want it to run until you reach the `'E'`.

   ```
   int sumPath(String[][] maze) {
       int sum = 0;
       int i = 0; // because you start at the top left
       int j = 0;

       while (!(maze[i][j].equals("E") && (!(maze[i][j].equals("0"))))) {

            if (maze[i][j].equals("R")) {
                j++; //move to the right (increase col)

            }
            else if (maze[i][j].equals("D")) {
                i++; //move down (increase row)

            }
            else if (maze[i][j].equals("L")) {
                j--; //move to the left (decrease col)

            }
            else if (maze[i][j].equals("U")) {
                i--; //move up (decrease row)

            }
            else { // just use an else block because you already checked all other options
                sum += Integer.parseInt(maze[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
   ```

This assumes that the maze is made correctly.
I can't check the code right now but this should work.